# Finding Anomalies in Gaussian Distribution using Covariance

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance

Say you have generated some two dimensional data (a, b) using a Gaussian distribution centered at (0, 0).

If you have a covariance matrix [1, -1/2, -1/2, 1], how do you find potential anomaly points?

For example (1, 0), (0, 1), are they anomaly points?

Or (1, -1)?

I was thinking you do not have the information necessary to solve.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "anomaly points"?

Comment: @RobertIsrael outliers

Comment: How do you define outliers?